# Data Custom Array Groupping C#

Tags: c#, arrays, types, mixed

I've been struggling to group some data into an array of this format:

http://pastebin.com/dxkCnzq3

In case your confused it would be something like this (number of type)

```
 new Array[Bool(2)][Bool(2)][Byte(3)][String(X)]
```

Where the number of strings is dynamic, and the else are fixed.

Is there any way to achieve this in c#?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "group"? Do you want to make a single structure/class that would hold these pieces of data together or you want a functionality similar to `GROUP BY` in SQL? Also, clarify your syntax: for example, what is `Bool(2)`? Array of 2 `Bool`s? Two `Bool` fields? Something else? Also, what is the meaning of the "mixed" tag?

Comment: I basicly want to create a multi-dimensional array of different types, I'm not asking for any group functionality.
For example as you would do int[,,] myArray = new int [4,2,3] -- I just dont want all the fields to be int.

Comment: Could it be that the bools and the bytes actually just are a composite key to reach the string array?

Comment: @JonasElfström Yes! 
I have read all the suggestions you people suggested and I'm going to experiment with them tommorow, and give you feedback on whether I managed it. Thanks everyone for your responses, if you have any more suggestions please say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of sounds that you could use a Tuple

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool, int, int, int>, string[]>();
dict[Tuple.Create(true, true, false, false, 2, 3, 5)] = new[] { "test", "pest" };
```

Answer (score 1):

As i understand u need tree structure. You can use some of these solutions: [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/trees.aspx), [two](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/GenericTreeCollection.aspx), [three](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/treecollection2.aspx), [four](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/phSharpTree.aspx).

Or create the tree structure by self:

```
class Byte
{
    byte value;
    string[] strings;
}

class Bool<T> where T: class
{
   bool value
   List<T> array;
}
```

And than use it:

```
Bool<bool> b1 = new Bool();
b1.array.Add(new Bool<Byte>());
```

And so on...